# How to fix 'Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'findRenderObject'' in dart with flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, hot-reload

When I hot reload the web app, I get this error.

This is the `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.10.14, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.10.14 at F:\flutter
• Framework revision 1946fc4 (2 weeks ago), 2019-10-07 15:23:31 -0700
• Engine revision 1d62160fdb
• Dart version 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.5.0 d6c6d12ebf)

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at F:\AndroidStudio
• Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
• Dart plugin version 191.8423
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
• Chrome • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 77.0.3865.120
• Headless Server • headless-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: This problem is fixed and commit is merged in master channel right now 
```
Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.15-pre.221, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-BD)
```
Sure it will soon be available in the dev and stable channel

Comment: I was using this version but I had to revert back to v1.10.14 due to some errors with 15 version.

Comment: Are you still having the same issue using the [latest release](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a [known issue for Flutter web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43451). As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43451#issuecomment-567252910), the bug have been fixed.

> All the listed issues have been fixed. Closing.
>
> - [Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'findRenderObject'
>   #41284](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41284) -> [DDC issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39020)
> - [Text editing broken in firefox in non-release builds #43450](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43450) -> [DDC issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37492)
> - [[web][Chrome][mobile] text editing state is transfered between fields #42769](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42769) ->
>   [Chrome
>   bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1014974)